# OpenCV and Php. Impossible?

Tags: php, opencv, pecl

See, i'm trying to use OpenCV in Php, but i cannot find a proper way to do it. Neither in stackoverflow.

Over the internet, i found two different ways to try:

---

1. Using this git. https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP

Problem: This code uses the dl function to import extensions on real-time execution , which has been removed from the last php versions (5.3 to 5.6 i think)

Solutions i've tried:

1. Link the extension .so at the php.ini file.
   Problem: The code dosen't has any opencv.so file
2. Downgrade my php 5.6 to 5.2
   Problem: Incompatibility with other parts of the code.

---

2. Using OpenCV Pecl package. http://pecl.php.net/package/opencv

Problem: The web shows the package but it has "no releases available". Neither if i try to download it on Centos using "(sudo) pecl download opencv". It gives me the same message, "no releases available. Download failed".

---

The thing is that i've seen a face-detection algorithm done with openCV over php, so i guess it is possible to use this library on Php. Anyone knows how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: forget about php bindings. they're all outdated/broken.

Comment: build a micro-service in python instead. (or just uses system(...))

Comment: Ty berak, i think im gonna go with system()...

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has only C++ and Python implementation ,and its strictly machine vision library,However if you write "web service" say Json to interact with the machine vision script ,you can then access it via php client request.

image--->'json'--->python facedetect---->image--->'json'---->php